# UITableView with CoreData objects being released

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm having a strange problem with a tableview and it's data. I have a long, about 253 objects list of Countries (NSManagedObjects) as datasource to fill the table.

The properties on the VC are defined as strong properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *originalCountries;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *countries;
```

I have some filtering logic and this is the reason for having these two arrays.

It's really weird but regarding the debugger the countries array used as datasource has 253 objects (with type Country) on it, but the attributes of the objects are all nil and for this the table is becoming "empty".

Here a capture of the debugger: [image]

My intuition says that the objects are being released by the "garbage collector" after some time, but I'm not sure. It's really curious for me that each bucket on the array points to a Country object and not to nil directly. It's curious for you too?. The problem is that with a big list of countries to select (or not) the user takes some time to do that and I lost my table data.

I'm using magical record to retrieve the objects that way:

```
self.countries = [Country MR_findAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];
self.originalCountries = [Country MR_findAllSortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];
```

If I get the original countries as a mutable copy of the countries the time spent to get the objects released is even lower. :(

Given this, the questions are: - What do you think about this situation? I've search a lot about a similar issue but I don't found anything. - Is there a way to say to the "garbage collector" don't release this objects too soon? - Maybe I'm missing something on the implementation of the table view? I can share some additional code maybe to complement the last question.

Many thanks for reading this far. Any kind of help is really appreciated. Happy new year for all.

EDIT 1 (More code related with UITableView delegate and datasource):

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.countries.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NextTripsCountriesListTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.arrowImageView.hidden = YES;

    Country *c = [self.countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.countryLabel.text = [c.name uppercaseString];
    cell.flagImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:c.flag];

    cell.numberOfDestinationsLabel.hidden = YES;

    if ([self.selectedCountries containsObject:c]) {
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"]];
        cell.accessoryView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#f95a30"];
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Country *c = [self.countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (self.configureForSingleSelection) {
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"]];
        cell.accessoryView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#f95a30"];
        [self.selectedCountries addObject:c];
        self.doneActionBlock(self.selectedCountries);
        [self.popupController dismiss];
    }
    else {
        if ([self.selectedCountries containsObject:c]) {
            [self.selectedCountries removeObject:c];
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"]];
            cell.accessoryView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#f95a30"];
            [self.selectedCountries addObject:c];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More code would be nice... Especially `UITableView` related.

Comment: I've updated the post @cojoj

Comment: I thought that maybe there was some sort of issue with `reuseIdentifier`, but  this looks fine.  
What can you see when you drop the `c` list in object inspector (the one on the left)? Can you see its properties or `nil`s?

Comment: it seems like self.countries populated with items, but those items' properties (e.g. name) are not properly assigned or initialised.

Comment: It is a NSManagedObject